# Do your companions care how you act?

Tags: fallout-4

I know that your companions will gain favor with you if you accept or complete a quest that matters to them.

But if I go around and steal some caps and they are with me, will they care?

What other things should I do or NOT do depending on what companion I have following me?

Comment: I know Codsworth loved that I painted flames on my Power Armor

Comment: List of general preferences: [What are the likes and dislikes of the companions?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246070/108003). Another answer has a partial list of more specific triggers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**

For a simple example, go to Sanctuary and ask Codsworth to be your companion. Use the flare gun to attract a couple killable NPCs and throw a grenade at them. The message "Codsworth hated that" should appear on the screen.

Moreover, you're able to ask the companion directly about their feelings on your relationship with them. After committing enough suitably negative acts, Codsworth in particular will comment that he "barely recognizes you as the man you once were," or something to that effect.

Comment: Flashbacks of Telltale games: *Codsworth will remember that.*

Comment: The one thing I'm not a big fan of with this is how they also react to certain dialog choices. If I want to try a persuasion option (i.e. bargain for more caps), Codsworth immediately questions my morality.

Comment: @DangerZone Worse, he didn't like when i used chems during a battle.

Comment: Wow... while that makes sense, it's kind of lame. I decided to stick with Nick Valentine for a while instead.

Comment: So far noticed Codsworth liked when I chose old-fashioned or honorable dialog options and Strong disliked when I picked a lock.

Comment: I heard they'll turn against you if you keep doing things they hate. Is that true?

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m Flashbacks of Life is Strange: _This action will have consequences (on Codsworth)._

Answer (score 3):

The short answer, at least until someone with better sources than I comes along is: yes, your companions do care.

I know at least Piper dislikes it if you try to weasel money/rewards out of people through the yellow/orange/red persuasion options.  She prefers it if you just offer to help people without badgering them for more stuff.

But, the only companions I know are the dog and Piper. You should be able to get an intuitive sense about what your current companion is after.  And, of course, the game will tell you when they like/dislike something - you should be able to figure out what it is they don't like about what you did.

Comment: A great follow-up question to this would be inquiring about the repercussions of these likes/dislikes, me+'C'.

Answer (score 1):

Very much, yes. A full chart of what each companion loves/likes/dislikes/hates can be found on the [Fallout 4 Companion wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions#Interests).

It's worth noting that a companion does not even need to be your active companion to like/dislike what you are doing if you are around them. It is possible (I do this to efficiently get the perks very early on) to increase your relationship with multiple companions by sending them to the same settlement and carrying out actions that they all approve of. (Danse, Garvey, and Codsworth all love when you modify/build armor and weaponry)