# Does sneak attack affect companion relationship?

Tags: fallout-4

My play style is mainly sneaking around and trying to get a headshot every time, and so far its been working quite well for me.

But I noticed that every now and then, my companion will make sarcastic comments that basically imply that I'm a coward for fighting this way (comments such as "Do we really have to do this?").

So far I've seen this happen with Codsworth and Piper (the only companions I have ATM aside from Dogmeat), are these just passing remarks, or do they affect the relationship with the companion? If they do, then who are the companions that dislikes sneak attack?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While they might leave sarcastic comment about it, the affinity of a companion is not influenced by it. No matter if you sneak a lot or run around like crazy, shooting everything.

However, not all actions are unjudged. For example, almost every follower hates it if you kill non-hostiles. A full list of affintiy factors can be found [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions).

Comment: Here's [a question and some answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246070/108003) on companion likes and dislikes.