# Companion quests when not using companions?

Tags: fallout-4

I find companions to be buggy and annoying, so I went for Lone Wandered path. However I would still like to do companion quests. What is the easiest way to get these, keeping using companions to minimum?

Comment: I feel this sort of question is way to broad. There would be specific strategies one could take, but a good answer multiplied by the amount of companions who each react differently, and thus would have a dofferent strategy, potentially blows this answer way out of the scope of arqade. I assume you want to do the quests for the perks, an alternative might be to assess which companions you wish to work on, and ask individual questions.

Comment: I was hoping for generic answer.

Comment: @Vartec Companion quests obviously require companions to be completed. So to keep your use of companions to a minimum you would just have to have them follow if you plan on completing a quest for them, or dismiss if you want to do anything else.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill your companion doesn't necessarily have to join you on their companion quest, I just did Nick Valentine's and while you do need him to be there at a few stops along the way, most of it can be done alone or with another companion.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I guess you want their perks. To quickly max out affinity do an action, save, reload save and do the same action again:

- Piper: Find a safe or locked door you can also unlock with a computer. Unlock the safe and relock it with the computer then save reload repeat.
- Codsworth & Curie (You can do both of them at once if they are in the same settlement after being you companion at least once): Take a piece of modified armor you find off a dead raider or so, take the mod off, save reload, put the mod back on save reload repeat. (armor is the best for this as taking a mod off the first time doesn't use any mats unlike weapons)
- Danse: Get in your power armor, get out of your power armor, save reload repeat.
- Cait: The same as Piper but I heard taking off all your clothes in a settlement and fast traveling to another settlement also works.

I really don't know about the other companions as I don't play with them.
If it's really the mission you want, Piper and Codsworth don't have a mission. Curie's mission can be done immediately, Cait needs max affinity for the mission to start. I'm not sure about Danse, he's my current companion and I haven't paid attention to him or his needs.

Comment: So, the affinity is stored externally to game progress?

Comment: Ow I get it now.. There is a period, I think about 5 minutes, where a companion will no longer raise affinity after doing something they like. This period can be overcome by saving after you have done the task and loading the save you just made.

Comment: ah thank you that makes sense - I thought the idea was to reload before the action and do it again, that's why I was confused!

Comment: Is it possible to wait or sleep instead of save/load?

Comment: Those are some of the easiest ones to repeat. You can find more information on companion likes and dislikes [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246070/108003). Also, a lot of companions like it when you heal Dogmeat, so if you get them all in a settlement and shoot him and heal him over and over, that can get you a long way.

Comment: @DCShannon: Wow, thats just... I don't have words for this *cuddle dogmeat*

Comment: Deacon likes it when you pick locks *and* when you hack computers, so he's really easy. Hancock likes it when you take chems (as does Cait, at first), which is pretty easy to repeat. Preston likes it when you mod weapons. Valentine likes it when you hack.

Comment: @Bounce Piper likes that.