# Will my romanced companion still be romanced if I join the Institute? (Fallout4)

Tags: fallout-4

So I romanced Maccready in Fallout4. I also just joined the Institute. But I'm wondering, if the institute is so secret, will Maccready still be romanced with me?

To be honest, I just really want to keep him as my romance option.

Answer (score 2):

Some companions are "faction affiliated." They get hostile if/when you attack their faction even if done it as part of a quest. As far as I know only Deacon, Danse, and X6-88 will either leave/attack you when you side with the opposite Faction.

Spoiler Warning:

> You may be able to remain friendly with Danse after he is outed from the Brotherhood for being a Synth if you side with him when they ask you to kill him.

Some are "Faction Neutral." McCready fall into this category, they do not leave you for taking action against one faction or another as far as I have noticed. Your actions may generate dislike depending on their personalities, but as long as you don't generate so much of it, to the point that they have warned you 2 or 3 times that you must change your ways, they will not leave. I think you're fine.

Comment: Pretty sure Preston is also faction affiliated and you'll lose him if you side with the institute

Answer (score 1):

[The Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Robert_Joseph_MacCready) for Maccready does not say that he dislikes joining the Institute as one of his dislikes. In fact, the word doesn't even appear on the page. [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246117/163757) does not say anything about the Institute either for Maccready.  You should be fine.

He does dislike if you join the Railroad or Brotherhood of Steel.  Even so, dislikes do not mean he will no longer be in a romance with you, unless he is on the edge about your relationship already.