# Can I get addicted to the mysterious serum?

Tags: fallout-4

During the missions Special Delivery and The Secret of Cabot House, some choices may lead to me being given a Mysterious Serum.  Is it possible for my character to become addicted to using it?

On a side note, Nick Valentine dislikes it if I open Lorenzo's cage, but is that all he dislikes in the mission, or will he permanently have some sort of hate against me if I let Lorenzo loose?

Comment: It's better to have one question per post. It makes it easier for people to find it by searching in the future.

Answer (score 7):

The [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mysterious_serum) says that you cannot get addicted to it (under the picture).

Also, under the notes section:

> Though the in-game consumable is not addictive for the player character, the Cabot family are psychologically addicted.

For the Nick Valentine part of your question, see [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246117/163757).  He shouldn't permanently hate you for doing that (there is no mentioning of it on the Wiki pages), but his affinity will drop.